# Reinitiate user defined jquery function on page resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've inherited some code from a previous developer who is now no longer contactable. I'm trying to get the function to reinitialize when the page is resized, but can't seem to get it to do so.

I'm a bit of a jQuery noob, which doesn't help.

The function is below:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.setWidth = function (o) {
        var vWidth = $("#wrapper").outerWidth(false) - 40;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried the following to reinitialize it when the page resizes, but currently nothing happens. No errors are generated either.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     $().setWidth();
});
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

-Edit-

Sorry, I should point out there is more code within the setWidth function, but I trimmed it out. I'm just trying to get the main function to reinitialize on resize.

Comment: What would you expect to happen?

Comment: What is the `o` argument? Where do you use `vWidth`? Why did you define that function on the jQuery prototype?

Comment: Well, `var vWidth = $("#wrapper").outerWidth(false)-40;` doesn't really do anything. It computes a value and stores it in `vWidth` and that's it. Nothing is done with `vWidth`. You won't see anything happen unless you set breakpoints inside the plugin. You should not add functions targeting specific elements to jQuery anyway.

Comment: Please share more code...

Comment: Is the defenition of `$.fn.setWidth` complete?

Comment: Ok, so what does the code do? What do you expect to see? A http://jsfiddle.net/ demo would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a function `function pageResize(){` that does the `var vWidth = $("#wrapper").outerWidth(false)-40;` code, you can then recall that on page resize.

So:

```
function pageResize(){
     var vWidth = $("#wrapper").outerWidth(false)-40;
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    pageResize();
});
```